# How to remove blank space in UI xml in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I have implemented the class and draw in canvas in xml. But I am facing blank space at the bottom of the UI. How can I solve this problem?? I use to draw a drawable on the canvas. The class name is BarcodeScannerView.
Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ui.scanqrcode.BarcodeReaderActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_base" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBarcodeValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="No Barcode Detected"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <com.tech.denTech.utils.QRCodeScannerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScanCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Scan QR code"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_8dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/ivScannerIcon"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivScannerIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_32dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_qr"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can go through this google link for screenshot:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KEQWjvubjlXs5hSENaShW9ErM84VXKY5/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: show your code, like the XML, or a screenshot of what you mean, or anything...

Comment: yes I edited with xml

Comment: and a screenshot, what do you mean by blank space?

Comment: Blundell As I am not able to share the picture on stackoverflow due to my low ranking but I can explain, there is small blank space at the bottom of UI with white color.

Comment: You can share a link to a picture on a 3rd party website. (Also filling out your profile gives you 50 rep IIRC)

Comment: here is link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KEQWjvubjlXs5hSENaShW9ErM84VXKY5/view?usp=sharing) and I didn't get 50 rep after filling out profilr.

Comment: You should and a badge :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195336/what-is-the-need-for-autobiographer-badge

Comment: check your layout in android studio design view. You can find some information there about gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Hierarchy Viewer to investigate:

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer

[image]

Then you can click on Views to understand what is what.

You can also look at the layout preview, to see which Views are taking up that space (if any):
[image: x]

Comment: Okay Thanks @Blundell I added my  surfaveView at the bottom of toolbar which I included and problem solved.